# Publishing NUnit Results in QuickBuild

Tags: quickbuild

I am working on CI tool by name QuickBuild, using this I am performing automated deployment with a single click.

Out build process includes following steps:

1. Get Latest Version
2. Build Code base
3. Validate DB
4. Perform Nunit
5. Publish the results, pass or fail

Under QuickBuild --> Steps --> Publish there are number of options to publish the results:

[image: Attached snapshot]

During NUnit testing .xml file will be generated and I am trying to publish .xml file to QuickBuild using Publish NUnit Report. In addition I have setup QuickBuild on remote sever and Nunit.xml file on build server which is a relative path.

When I create a step and execute it, it fail to read the XML file (size more than 2 MB). Is there a way to see the all ready ran nUNit results in QuickBuild UI.

I have tried with other file formats (.log, .html) no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your error messages which can help know more about your problems. You can find the error messages in your build log. By the way, the publish step only accept XML format by default. Also, please follow the instructions below:

http://wiki.pmease.com/display/QB50/Publish+NUnit+Report